# Allow only one Thread to access a particular file in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io

I have a folder with large number of files in it. There is one cron job that takes 10 file names at a time e.g. file1, file2....., file10 and creates 10 new Threads to read those files. The content of those files is extracted and dumped in another process(irrelevant) and the file is deleted

Now the problem is that if one of the Threads takes more than a minute to process the file, the cron job triggers again and picks up the same file again as it is not deleted yet and processes the content again.

Is there a way to restrict Thread from reading a file/creating a File object if there is another Thread already reading content from it.

I can have a synchronized hash map store the details of 10 files that the 10 Threads are currently processing and check the map before I assign a file to a Thread but I am finding it difficult to believe that is there is no better way to do this in Java.

Comment: could try moving or renaming the file that is being processed so that it would not be picked up by the cron the next time

Comment: @Guenther - the said thread describes FileChannel.Lock which is per JVM lock rather than a per thread lock (where the threads are within the same JVM) and hence clearly not what the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need a "sync point" between your different threads; for that, there are plenty of options.

When all your threads are running in the same JVM, then you could use a class like

```
class CurrentlyProcessedFilesTracker {
  synchronized void markFileForProcessing(File f) { }
  synchronized void markFileAsDone(File f) {
```

or something alike (where the first one would throw an exception in case the provided file is already known).

Then you just have to make sure that all your threads have access to the same instance of that class ... and they use it to "lock" and "unlock" while being busy working a certain file.

If there is more than one JVM, things become more complicated. Then you would need either some inter-process communication; or you go for the idea from Scary Wombat and have the "scheduler part" rename files (depending on your context that might a good idea; or not; it depends what other "responsibilities" that scheduler part has - you shouldn't put too much things into that one component).